# Change td content according to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table for assignments. **TABLE1** has the data of the assignments posted by a faculty and **TABLE2** has data of those students who submitted the assignments. Both table have one similar column called '**assignment name**'.

My **TABLE2** has a status column which is boolean data. By default i have set it to 0 and if a student submit his assignment that changes to 1.

In my HTML page (student side) I'm displaying the data from **TABLE1** in a table. It shows all assignments name and I have given a submit status column there which will show if the assignment work is submitted by the logged in student. If yes it will show a check icon if not then a times icon.

This is what i have tried:

```
<?php
session_start();
include'connection.php';
$user=$_SESSION['details1'];
$query =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT course FROM student WHERE username='$user'");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $cr=$row['course'];
            }
$query1 =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT semester FROM student WHERE username='$user'");
            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
            {
                $sems=$row1['semester'];
            }
$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM submitted_assignments WHERE s_name='$user'");
            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $stat=$row2['status'];
            }
?>
<table class="student" id= "student">
<form action="" method="post">
<thead>
<tr class="table100-head">
<th class="column0">Sl. No.</th>
<th class="column2">Assignment Name</th>
<th class="column2">Subject</th>
<th class="column1">Date</th>
<th class="column0">View</th>
<th class="column0">Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
                    <?php
                $shcat=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM assignment INNER JOIN subject ON assignment.as_subject=subject.s_id WHERE s_course='$cr' AND a_semester='$sems'");
                $cnt=1;
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($shcat)){
                    $stat = 0;
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM submitted_assignments WHERE s_name='$user' AND a_name=".$row['a_id']);
                    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                    $stat=$row2['status'];
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="column0"><?php echo $cnt; ?></td>
                        <td class="column1"><?php echo $row['a_name'];?></td>
                        <td class="column2"><?php echo $row['s_name'];?></td>
                        <td class="column2"><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                        <td class="column0"><a target = "_blank" href="../faculty/assignment/<?php echo $row['image']?>"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></td>
                        <?php 
                        if ($stat == 0){ ?>
                        <td class="column0"><i class="fa fa-times" title="Not Submitted"></i></td>
                        <?php } 
                        else {?>
                        <td class="column0"><i class="fa fa-check" title="Submitted"></i></td>
                        <?php }?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $cnt=$cnt+1; 
                    } ?>
                        </tbody>
                        </form>
                    </table>
```

From what i have tried it changes all the **rows** to check icon even if only one row's assignment is submitted.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit** Its working now.

Comment: Please provide your full code, where and how is $stat being set, and are your rows within a php loop?

Comment: I have edited my code @Zachary.Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to set `$stat`

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM submitted_assignments WHERE s_name='$user'");
            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $stat=$row2['status'];
            }
```

is just going to override the value of `$stat` leaving the last rows value in its place.

The simple way to fix this will be to move this sql into the PHP for loop and check for the specific assignment+user combination. Without your database scheme im not sure the files used but something like:

```
                <?php
                $shcat=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM assignment INNER JOIN subject ON assignment.as_subject=subject.s_id WHERE s_course='$cr' and a_semester='$sems'");
                $cnt=1;
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($shcat)){
                    $stat = 0;
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM submitted_assignments WHERE s_name='$user' AND a_name=".$row['a_name']);
                    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        $stat=$row2['status'];
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="column0"><?php echo $cnt; ?></td>
                        <td class="column1"><?php echo $row['a_name'];?></td>
                        <td class="column2"><?php echo $row['s_name'];?></td>
                        <td class="column2"><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                        <td class="column0"><a target = "_blank" href="../faculty/assignment/<?php echo $row['image']?>"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></td>
                        <?php 
                        if ($stat == 0){ ?>
                        <td class="column0"><i class="fa fa-times" title="Not Submitted"></i></td>
                        <?php } 
                        else {?>
                        <td class="column0"><i class="fa fa-check" title="Submitted"></i></td>
                        <?php }?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $cnt=$cnt+1; 
                    } ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in this line :  $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status FROM submitted_assignments WHERE s_name='$user' AND a_name='$row['a_name']'");

Comment: i tried storing "a_name" in a variable and then the error was gone but the problem with table status didnt solve after submitting. But all other errors are gone now.

Comment: Thank you @Zachary . Your code is working. Since a_name in my TABLE2 is the key from TABLE1 i replaced a_name with a_id in ur code and now its showing expected results. Sorry for the confusion.